# Update a line at specific line and section

Tags: shell, unix

I have file and content has like below.

```
servers:
# Start OF VM1
- displayName: "I_INST1_1"
  includeQueues: [test1,test2,test3]
  excludeTopics: []
# End OF VM1
# Start OF VM2
- displayName: "I_INST1_2"
  includeQueues: []
  excludeTopics: []
# End OF VM2
```

I wanted to update the line for includeQueue section with [test1,test2,test3] only between the lines where from # Start OF VM1 to # End OF VM1

Could some one help me how to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried already and were do you stuck?

Comment: sed -n '/# Start OF I_EMS_2/,/# End OF I_EMS_2/p' config.yml | grep includeQueues | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' I tried till here But PS has given the solution. Trying to make syntax with variables instead of hard code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will select the range of records between "Start OF VM1" and "End OF VM1" and then apply `gsub` function over that chunk of records. where `[]` is replaced with `[test1,test2,test,*]`.

```
 awk '/Start OF VM1/,/End OF VM1/{if( $0 ~/includeQueues/ )gsub(/\[\]/,"[test1,test2,test,*]")}1'
------------------------------------------------
#########
## If xxxx:
##
servers:
# Start OF VM1
   - displayName: "I_INST1_1"
     includeQueues: [test1,test2,test,*]
     excludeTopics: []
# End OF VM1
# Start OF VM2
   - displayName: "I_INST1_2"
     includeQueues: []
     excludeTopics: []
# End OF VM2
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi PS, I wanted to update includeQueues parameter only in the actual file  i have many parameters like xyz: [] abc: []..  We need grep includeQueues parameter and then update text

Comment: Yes. Only for includeQueues parameter

Comment: Just one question, if i want to declare Start OF VM1 , End OF VM1 and test1,test2,test,* as variable something like $value1 $value2 and $value3. Then how can I declare

Comment: You need to declare them at the start of the `awk` statement like : 

`awk -v var1="$value1" -v var2="$value2" {........}`

Comment: awk '/# Start OF \"$V1\"/,/# End OF \"$V1\"/{if( $0 ~/includeQueues/ )gsub(/\[\]/,"[\"$V2\"]")}1' i tried like this .. but it's not updating now

Comment: It;s working with below command.
awk '/# Start OF '$V1'/,/# End OF '$V1'/{if( $0 ~/includeQueues/ )gsub(/\[\]/,"['$V2']")}1' config.yml

if some value already present it's not updating,.. please help here

Comment: It's removing the existed data and replacing with new but I want to append the data

Comment: try `awk '/Start OF VM1/,/End OF VM1/{if( $0 ~/includeQueues/ )gsub(/\[/,"&""test1,test2,test" )}1'`

Comment: @SureshchandraJarugula any reason for not accepting the answer ?

Comment: Hi PS, Just updated the question. The command works if the file having unique lines, but file having duplicates lines for each section, it's not.

Comment: I think you should really ask new question as you have changes the input(Initial condition). We would be glad to help.

Comment: Okey. I did not know that, let me ask new question.

Comment: Please revert this question to original state else all the answers would go wrong.

Comment: I have reverted the changes and also accepted your answer. Thanks.

Comment: PS. I posted new question with the name "Update a specific line with data". Could you please help to update

Comment: your question is marked duplicate of some other question so  I cannot answer. However, You can try reading the question which is tagged as duplicate for some idea. If that didnt help let me know.

Comment: no, it's reopened the ticket as it was not duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '/End OF VM1/{A=""} /Start OF VM1/{A=1} A && /includeQueues/{$0="includeQueues: [test1,test2,test,*]"} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Apologies Toby, sometimes if busy in work so couldn't write explanation, I will add it in some time for sure.